# Changing tabs in Vaadin 14 causes the splitter window to revert back to default split location

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

In Vaadin 14.4.2, I have a dialog box with tabs; in the 1st tab, I have a splitter. I resize the splitter and it looks good (fig 1). But, if I click on another tab (eg "Quant By Sample") and then return back to the 1st tab (original tab from figure 1), it has FORGOTTEN the location of my splitter. (See fig 2); Instead, it seems to have "refreshed" the screen with the defualt location of the splitter. Is this a bug? If so, is there a safe/stable workaround (or should we just wait for a fix?)

Fig 1: On 1st tab, and after resizing
[image]

Fig 2: After I click on another tab and then return back to the original tab:
[image]

Comment: There is no TabSheet component in Vaadin 14, so the behavior depends on how you've implemented the tab to content mapping? Are you showing/hiding components or detaching and re-attaching them? Are you perhaps always creating a new instance of the tab content when you change tabs?

Comment: There are a handful of different workarounds here: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-split-layout/issues/152